# Create a glowing border in QSS

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, border, qtstylesheets

How would one go about create a glowing border around a button when a user hovers over it in PyQT4 QSS? I'm speaking of something similar to the `box-shadow`in CSS.

```
someButton:hover {
    border:1px solid black;
    /*Glowing code here?*/
}
```

[image: http://0.tqn.com/d/webdesign/1/5/m/l/1/glow-effect.png]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this, would be to use [setGraphicsEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setGraphicsEffect) with a [QGraphicsDropShadowEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html):

```
    effect = QtGui.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(button)
    effect.setOffset(0, 0)
    effect.setBlurRadius(20)
    button.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
```